# Django- jQuery and tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

I'm using an app that stores/manages forms. I've been wanting to list all the forms in a page, and if the user clicks on a form name, then that form is fetched (via jQuery?) and presented in that same page, beneath the form list, so that the user can fill it and submit!

The person who made this app left a template to get the html for a specific form, as for example `{% render_built_form slug=form_instance.slug %}`

I'm very confused about the correct way to go at this. Is it possible/correct to use a scheme like:

1. (The list of forms is presented, using some Javascript to make a Button for each of them)
2. When a user clicks on a button, the corresponding form (html string) is fetched, somehow using the tag (with the form's slug in there) 'inside' jQuery
3. The html form is displayed beneath the list and the user can now fill it.

Is this a correct/feasible idea, or am I confusing these concepts? If so, pointers on how to use jQuery with a tag would be super helpful.

Comment: Seems like you have the right idea.

Comment: I've now completed the whole 'sequence', and confirmed that the general idea I asked about is correct. Even the extra of having an asynchronous POST to then submit the forms. Thanks

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've confirmed that my idea is doable, as I've implemented it and it runs OK. There's even an extra thing I've implemented that I didn't mention, of asynchronous POSTing of the filled forms. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good approach.
I won't write it all for you! :-) But, I will give you a few pointers and links on where to start.

1a. Your "list" of forms you can pass down to a template from your view.py file. The template engine is probably like [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) or [python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/) templates. Your list and view will look like this.

```
    def form_view_function(request):
        list_of_dict_items = {
            forms: [{
                name:'form one',
                target: '/form_one_link'
            },{
                name:'form two',
                target: '/form_two_target'
            }]}

    return render_to_response("my_template_folder/forms.html", list_of_dict_items)
```

1b. Template forms.html:

```
{% for item in forms %}
     <button onClick=function_to_target({{ item.target }})>{{item.name}}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

2 & 3. There are several ways to handle the dynamic loading of your forms. with Ajax call. Most are covered in these two blogs: http://racingtadpole.com/blog/django-ajax-and-jquery/ and https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/.

Hope this will get you started!

Comment: Your answer is really weird, given that I'd already said in another answer (and a comment) that I've already implemented the idea and it runs ok

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question.  I thought you needed tips on how to render the form data in the template. And, then further pointers to how to fetch the forms and post the complete data back to Django.  
If it all works okay. Why don't you post the code to complete your answer?